# How to track buys and sells from a Token on the solana chain?

Tags: transactions, token, transaction, mint, help

i'm trying to track buys and sells from 1 token on the solana chain. But i don't get it properly done to receive every buy and every sell from this token, and get the correct amount of tokens that have been bought or sold. I receive in the console sometimes the correct amount . But also allot of times there was a buy or sell but the code didn't track it.

this is the code i have, i hope i can get some help.

```
const solanaweb3 = require('@solana/web3.js');

const searchAddress = 'The token contract address';
const endpoint = 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com'; // https://api.devnet.solana.com or https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
const solanaConnection = new solanaweb3.Connection(endpoint);
const processedSignatures = new Set(); // Set to store processed signatures

const getTransactions = async (address, numTx) => {
    const pubKey = new solanaweb3.PublicKey(address);
    while (true) {
        try {
            let transactionList = await solanaConnection.getSignaturesForAddress(pubKey, { limit: numTx });

            let signatureList = transactionList.map(transaction => transaction.signature);
            let transactionDetails = await solanaConnection.getParsedTransactions(signatureList, { maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0 });

            for (let i = 0; i < transactionList.length; i++) {
                const transaction = transactionList[i];
                const signature = transaction.signature;

                // Check if the signature has already been processed
                if (processedSignatures.has(signature)) {
                    console.log(`Signature ${signature} has already been processed. Skipping.`);
                    continue; // Skip processing this transaction
                }

                // Mark the signature as processed
                processedSignatures.add(signature);

                const date = new Date(transaction.blockTime * 1000);
                const Transactions = transactionDetails[i];
                const transactionInstructions = Transactions.transaction.message.instructions;
                //console.log('metadata:', Transactions.meta)
                //console.log('Transactions:', Transactions.meta.preTokenBalances);
                console.log(`Transaction No: ${i + 1}`);
                console.log(`Signature: ${signature}`);
                console.log(`Time: ${date}`);
                console.log(`Status: ${transaction.confirmationStatus}`);

                // Find the token balances before and after the transaction
                const preBalance = Transactions.meta.preTokenBalances.find(balance => balance.mint === searchAddress);
                const postBalance = Transactions.meta.postTokenBalances.find(balance => balance.mint === searchAddress);

                if (preBalance && postBalance) {
                    // Calculate the difference in token balance
                    const Diff = postBalance.uiTokenAmount.uiAmount - preBalance.uiTokenAmount.uiAmount;

                    console.log(` tokens bought/sold: ${Math.abs(Diff)}`);
                    console.log(` tokens bought: ${Diff > 0 ? Diff : 0}`);
                    console.log(` tokens sold: ${Diff < 0 ? Math.abs(Diff) : 0}`);
                } else {
                    console.log(' token balance not found in transaction metadata.');
                }

                // Check if the transaction is successful
                const isSuccess = transaction.confirmationStatus === 'confirmed';
                console.log(transaction.err)
                // Check if the transaction has an instruction error
                if (Transactions.meta && Transactions.meta.err) {
                    const instructionError = Transactions.meta.err;
                    console.log(`Transaction ${signature} encountered an instruction error:`, instructionError);
                }
                if (isSuccess) {
                    // Transaction is successful
                    console.log(`Transaction ${signature} is successful.`);
                } else {
                    // Transaction is failed or not yet finalized
                    console.log(`Transaction ${signature} has not been confirmed or has failed.`);
                }

                // Search for the first occurrence of the mint address with non-zero amount
                const foundInstruction = Transactions.meta.preTokenBalances.find(instruction => {
                    return instruction.mint === searchAddress && instruction.uiTokenAmount.uiAmountString !== '0';
                });
                if (foundInstruction) {
                    console.log('Found first instruction with non-zero amount for mint address:', searchAddress);
                    console.log('uiAmountString:', foundInstruction.uiTokenAmount.uiAmountString);
                    break; // Stop searching after finding the first occurrence
                } else {
                    console.log(`No non-zero amount found for mint address: ${searchAddress}`);
                }

                console.log("-".repeat(20));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error occurred:', error);
        }
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 15000)); // Wait for 15 seconds before fetching transactions again
    }
};

getTransactions(searchAddress, 1);
```